# .htaccess: How to remove subfolder's subfolder in URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect this URL `www.domain.com/~username` to `www.domain.com/~username/public` but remove the `/public` from the URL.

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /~username/public/~username/ was not found on this server.
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~username/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly. Could you explain what you added to make this work? It'd be great for future reference.

Comment: Main problem was your use of `%{REQUEST_URI}` which contains full URI from root, not just the relative URL from current directory as the `$1` here.