# How to hide subfolder's subfolder from htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, hide, subdirectory

I've done something in my .htacces to remove www and /example.com/ subfolder.
It worked fine, but when I tried to access the real subfolder, it redirects me to full url

The valid urls I want are;
**example.com**
**example.com/app**
**example.com/admin**

If i hit **example.com** it works fine,
but when I hit **example.com/app**, it redirects to **example.com/example.com/app**

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092810/htaccess-how-to-remove-subfolders-subfolder-in-url) way, but still doesn't work

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule !^example.com/ /example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

btw, my folder structure

```
public_html
 └ .htaccess
 └ example.com
   └ app
   └ admin
```