# What I need to do in order to open URLs with special characters

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, slug

Hi i am trying to make a seo friendly url using php. I am using the follwoing code to converting the url like `exapmle.com/post/hi-how-are-you` and also using this .htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)/?$ single_post.php?blog_title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

php slug url

```
function url_slug($str) {   
    $str = mb_strtolower(trim($str), 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace('/[[:^alnum:]]/iu', ' ', $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

But the problem is special character. For example: When i post some turkih character like (tırda bir öğün çok çıktı) the url looks like this

```
example.com/post/tırda-bir-öğün-çok-çıktı
```

Everything is ok for the slug but when i open the url i can not GETting any data with (tırda-bir-öğün-çok-çıktı).

**What do I need to do in order to open URLs with special characters?**

Do we have a chance to print all special characters in English? Like when i post something from data the url_slug can change the special character to english character for example:

```
tırda bir öğün çok çıktı
```

converted english character

```
tirda-bir-ogun-cok-cikti
```

Comment: [`echo 'example.com/post/'.urlencode( 'tırda bir öğün çok çıktı' );`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) exists for precisely this purpose so that you end up with `example.com/post/t%C4%B1rda%20bir%20%C3%B6%C4%9F%C3%BCn%20%C3%A7ok%20%C3%A7%C4%B1kt%C4%B1`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Actually it will encode it only, not convert to user-friendly.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That is not converting user-friendly

Comment: @Azzo You asked for "seo-friendly". Google should have no trouble deciphering properly encoded links on your site so if someone is actually searching for `öğün` then they should see your article. Converting it to `ogun` negates that benefit.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Again you are wrong. Google will convert non-latin letters to it's representation in lattin, so it will be fine, because all letters has it's representation.

Comment: @Justinas If that is true then why does Googling `öğün` produce different results than `ogun`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches word characters only where word char is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and it doesn't include all unicode characters.

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ single_post.php?blog_title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`[^/]+` will match any character that is not `/` including unicode characters as well.

You may also tweak php code a bit:

```
function url_slug($str) {   
    $str = mb_strtolower(trim($str), 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace('/[^\pL\pN]+/u', ' ', $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\h+/', '-', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for not breaking me and answering me.

Comment: Can i ask you one question dear if you have a time ? I switch the page with php switch the file is in the pages folder so my question is how can i get the url using `htaccess` like this `http://localhost://8888/group/name` . There are no group folder i just wont to show group in the url. Is it possible if yes how ?

Comment: i have tryed like this but some included php files not displayed: `RewriteRule ^group/([\w-]+)/?$ sources/group.php?group_username=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Dear i have asked the question from this link can you check it for me please ? [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533823/show-the-link-as-if-it-was-linked-to-the-file-using-htaccess)

Comment: i am waiting for you Dear

Comment: Dear is it possible to remove the `play` subfolder name from the url using htaccess ? `RewriteRule ^play/([\w-]+)/?$ play.php?set=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: dear i mean i ebat to remove play from the URL like: https://www.websiteaddress.com/play so the current URL is HTTPS://ww.websiteaddress.com/play/play is it possible?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27096994/548225 and if it doesn't work then please open a new question describing your problem clearly with your current .htaccess shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

Most common way is to use some mapping where you have non-latin letter as key and Latin letter representation:

```
$map = [
   'š' => 'sh',
   ...
];
```

Then you use replace:

```
str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $slug);
```

---

Another way is using [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $slug);
```

Comment: so `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $slug);` converting all special character ?